# Activating a different section of a JQuery Accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

I'd really appreciate any help with this problem.

This is a much simplified version of a longer set of php code, but it still has the problem, so I've ruled out the rest as the cause.

The accordion is being created in the  of the main page.  The HTML that follows is generated by an included php file.

The accordion works perfectly, the only problem is that sometimes I will want to load the second section (Section W) instead of the first (Section R) as is the default behaviour.  I've tried several solutions that I have found online, but none of the ones below work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code: http://pastebin.com/WQfctKVx

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function() {
        $( "#k_accordion" ).accordion({
            autoHeight: false,
            navigation: true
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="k_accordion">
    <h3 id="sectionR"><a href="#sectionR">Section R</a></h3>
    <div>
        Content for Section R
    </div>

    <h3 id="sectionW"><a href="#sectionW">Section W</a></h3>
    <div>
        Content for Section W
    </div>

    <script language=javascript> $( "#k_accordion" ).accordion( "activate", 2);</script>
    <script language=javascript>// Gives 'is not a function' error:     $("#k_accordion").activate(2); </script>
    <script language=javascript>// $( "#k_accordion" ).accordion( "activate", "sectionW");</script>
    <script language=javascript>// $( "#k_accordion" ).accordion( "activate", "#k_accordion > div:has(#sectionW) > h3"); </script>
    <script language=javascript>// $( "#k_accordion" ).accordion( "activate", $("#h3-sectionW")); </script>
</div>
```

Comment: It's better if you paste the code directly into your answer (indented 4 spaces) so it's more convenient for us to read and your question doesn't die if the pastebin does. Plus we can search it from SO.

Comment: Oh thanks for doing that. I pasted it in originally but edited it out because it didn't show up properly.  I'll have a look at how to add it in properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`active` option](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active) is what you need:

> **activeType: Boolean or Integer**
>   Default: 0
>
> Which panel is currently open.
>
> **Multiple types supported:**
>
> - **Boolean**: Setting `active` to `false` will collapse all panels. This requires the `collapsible option` to be true.
> - **Integer**: The zero-based index of the panel that is active (open). A negative value selects panels going backward from the last panel.

If you want the second panel open (for example), then set `active: 1` when creating the accordion:

```
$( "#k_accordion" ).accordion({
    autoHeight: false,
    navigation: true,
    active: 1
});
```

Or you can use the `option` method to change the open panel after the accordion is created:

```
$('#k_accordion').accordion('option', 'active', 1);
```

Or you can use the `activate` method:

```
$("#k_accordion").accordion('activate', 1);
```

Just remember two things when using the `active` option or the `activate` method:

1. They want panel indexes, not `id` attributes.
2. The indexes are zero-based (just like JavaScript arrays) so the second panel has an index of 1 rather than the 2 that you were trying to use.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  Adding 'active: 1' to the creation of the accordion worked.  The other two options didn't work and I have no idea why not, but it's working now, so I'm very grateful as I've been stuck on this for hours.